# Invalid schema, expected `mongodb` or `mongodb+srv`

Tags: node.js, mongodb

have a problem, one project simple node js app with adding and getting data from user and saving into mongo (use 3.. ver), everything OK (saving, getting etc), example is

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongo = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var objectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
var assert = require('assert');

const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';
const dbName = 'ldex';
const tblOffers = 'offers';

router.post('/insert', function (req, res, next) {
    var order = {
        type: 'Sell',
        ..............
        max: req.body.max,
        protection: req.body.protection,
        comment: req.body.comment,
        date: new Date().toDateString()
    };

    mongo.connect(url, function (err, client) {
        assert.equal(null, err);

        const db = client.db(dbName);

        db.collection(tblOffers).insertOne(order, function (err, res) {
            assert.equal(null, err);
            console.log('Offer placed');
            client.close();
        })
    });

    res.redirect('/exchange')
});
```

But here is another app, parser, that have the same mongo connection, it's adding some data in it from other web-site (when do not use mongo all ok, I recieve data well), here is the part of code:

```
...
let assert = require('assert');
let mongo = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
let router = express.Router();

const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/';
const dbName = 'ceramo';
const tblOffers = 'items';

...

/*
 *  Get items from specific group
 */

function getGroupItems(url, callback) {
    request({uri: url}, function (error, response, body) {
        let list = [];
        let $ = cheerio.load(body);
        $('#tovar').find('a.cat_item_disc_a').each(function(i, elem) {
            list[i] = 'https://plitkazavr.ru' + $(this).attr('href');
        });
        callback(list);
    });
}

/*
 *  Parse one item from specific link
 */

function getItem(url) {
    request({uri: url}, function (error, response, body) {
        let list = {};
        let $ = cheerio.load(body);
        $('#item_border').find('> #item_prop > ul').find('li.item_list').each(function(i, elem) {
            list[$(this).find('.item_cell').first().text()] = $(this).find('div.item_cell.item_val').text();
        });
        list.price = (parseFloat($('#item_price').text()));
        list.img = ('https://plitkazavr.ru' + $('#item_img').attr('src'));
        list.meta = ($('#item_wrap').find('meta[itemprop="description"]').attr("content"));

        mongo.connect(url, function (err, client) {
            assert.equal(null, err);

            const db = client.db(dbName);

            db.collection(tblOffers).insertOne(order, function (err, res) {
                assert.equal(null, err);
                console.log('Offer placed');
                client.close();
            })
        });

    });
}

router.get('/parse', function (req, res, next) {

    getGroupItems('https://plitkazavr.ru/Naxos/Clio', function (items) {
        items.forEach(function(item, i, arr) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                getItem(item);
            }, 1000);
        });
    });

    res.end('ok');
});
```

And it's down on connection and gives the

```
`Error: Invalid schema, expected `mongodb` or `mongodb+srv
```

Don't understand where is a problem, help please...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your MongoDB URL seems incomplete, it should include your `dbName` before it's passed into the mongoose connection like this

```
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/';
const fullUrl = url + dbName; // which should evaluate to this 'mongodb://localhost:27017/ceramo'


mongo.connect(fullUrl, function (err, client) {...}
```

Comment: You're welcome, please upvote my answer if it helped you. @EvgenyGil

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly answer to your question but my problem was that environment variable value was wrapped in unnecessary apostrophes `MONGODB_CONNECTION_URL="'mongodb:...'"`. So it was reporting:

> Error: Invalid schema, expected `mongodb` or `mongodb+srv