# Facing issue during connect the Mongo DB atlas

Tags: mongodb

```js
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const dbURI =
  "mongodb+srv://<User name>:<Password>@cluster0-duxly.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true";
    
  MongoClient.connect(dbURI, function(err, client) {
    if(err) {
         console.log('Error occurred while connecting to MongoDB Atlas...\n',err);
    }
    
    console.log('Connected...');
    const collection = client.db("test").collection("devices");
    // perform actions on the collection object
    client.close();
 });


// require any models

require("../model/task");
```

Above mentioned is the code to the connection of Mongo DB cluster.

The error comes like this

> throw new Error('invalid schema, expected MongoDB');
>       ^
>
> Error: invalid schema, expected MongoDB

Comment: please provide code sample as inline text instead of screenshot

Comment: hi i just edit my qn and add the code instead of screen shoat pls let me know what to do.

Comment: check these answers out : https://stackoverflow.com/q/48605217/9144250

Comment: thanks for the answer but I am using the cluster of Mongo db so the url suggestion but its for the local mongo db . here i am using the cluster of that. If  I am wrong pls tell me